# Need help to install Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, python-3.10

No matter what i try, kivy always fails to install. I can install most other packages but not kivy. I tried it through pycharm, reinstalling python, and trying every command on cmd prompt, it just won't install.

This is the errors i get:

```
C:\Program Files\Python 3.10.0>python -m pip install kivy==2.0.0
Collecting kivy==2.0.0
  Using cached Kivy-2.0.0.tar.gz (23.7 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Program Files\Python 3.10.0\python.exe' 'C:\Users\ranta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-standalone-pip-12uaq80_\__env_pip__.zip\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\ranta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-pi2ci1b2\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'cython>=0.24,<=0.29.21,!=0.27,!=0.27.2' 'kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev~=0.3.1; sys_platform == "win32"' 'kivy_deps.sdl2_dev~=0.3.1; sys_platform == "win32"' 'kivy_deps.glew_dev~=0.3.0; sys_platform == "win32"' 'kivy_deps.gstreamer~=0.3.1; sys_platform == "win32"' 'kivy_deps.sdl2~=0.3.1; sys_platform == "win32"' 'kivy_deps.glew~=0.3.0; sys_platform == "win32"'
       cwd: None
  Complete output (10 lines):
  Collecting setuptools
    Using cached setuptools-58.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (946 kB)
  Collecting wheel
    Using cached wheel-0.37.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
  Collecting cython!=0.27,!=0.27.2,<=0.29.21,>=0.24
    Using cached Cython-0.29.21-py2.py3-none-any.whl (974 kB)
  Collecting kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev~=0.3.1
    Using cached kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev-0.3.2-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (3.9 MB)
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement kivy_deps.sdl2_dev~=0.3.1 (from versions: 0.4.2, 0.4.3)
  ERROR: No matching distribution found for kivy_deps.sdl2_dev~=0.3.1
  ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/12/96/091ddacafb84dd18555a32d860dbfaf9c806147aa30c6f3c8b93cb7bab97/Kivy-2.0.0.tar.gz#sha256=d25e44eb44e43762b2fd0c5874e51954e0f1181fd9800d8a6756be6d084812d8 (from https://pypi.org/simple/kivy/). Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Program Files\Python 3.10.0\python.exe' 'C:\Users\ranta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-standalone-pip-12uaq80_\__env_pip__.zip\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\ranta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-pi2ci1b2\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'cython>=0.24,<=0.29.21,!=0.27,!=0.27.2' 'kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev~=0.3.1; sys_platform == "win32"' 'kivy_deps.sdl2_dev~=0.3.1; sys_platform == "win32"' 'kivy_deps.glew_dev~=0.3.0; sys_platform == "win32"' 'kivy_deps.gstreamer~=0.3.1; sys_platform == "win32"' 'kivy_deps.sdl2~=0.3.1; sys_platform == "win32"' 'kivy_deps.glew~=0.3.0; sys_platform == "win32"' Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement kivy==2.0.0 (from versions: 1.0.1a0, 1.0.2a0, 1.0.3a0, 1.0.4b0, 1.0.5, 1.0.6, 1.0.7, 1.0.8, 1.0.9, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.2.0, 1.3.0, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.6.0, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.8.0, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.10.0, 1.10.1, 1.11.0rc1, 1.11.0rc2, 1.11.0, 1.11.1, 2.0.0rc1, 2.0.0rc2, 2.0.0rc3, 2.0.0rc4, 2.0.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for kivy==2.0.0
```

END OF ERROR

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: Kivy now supports 3.10: https://kivy.org/doc/master/gettingstarted/installation.html#install-kivy

Did some research at [their PyPI page](https://pypi.org/project/Kivy/#files) and [their GitHub](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/releases)

It looks like Kivy doesn't support Python 3.10 **yet**. ([GitHub issue](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/7654#issuecomment-949975555))

Kivy currently supports Python 3.6 - 3.9

Comment: Thank you. However, i have tried it with. Python 3.9.0, and the same errors persist

Comment: Did you resolve this? I had no problem installing kivy with pip after downgrading to 3.9.9

Comment: Kivy now supports 3.10, it is not a stable version so bugs may occur: https://kivy.org/doc/master/gettingstarted/installation.html#install-kivy I have updated the post

Comment: I created a new environment in miniconda with 3.10, then did a pip install kivy and it failed. Then I create another environment based on 3.9 and kivy installed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and I can solve this by uninstall python 3.10, and it works with python 3.9.
After uninstall python 3.10 I followed the steps in [kivy's installing page](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/gettingstarted/installation.html) and it works. While I followed this steps, my virtual environment was created in python 3.8.8 (Python 3.8.8 64-bit ('kivy_venv':venv)), I don't know why but at least it works.

Comment: I am working in a Windows machine with VS code.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30771521)

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same issue and resolved it by uninstalling 3.10 and installing 3.9.10.