# ERROR: No matching distribution found for kivy_deps.sdl2_dev~=0.4.5

Tags: python, kivy

I did all the whole process to install Kivy...

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools
python -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2 kivy.deps.glew
python -m pip install kivy.deps.gstreamer
python -m pip install kivy.deps.angle
python -m pip install pygame
python -m pip install kivy
```

but once i get to the last pip install kivy i get the next message in the console:

````
    
```
Collecting kivy
     Using cached Kivy-2.1.0.tar.gz (23.8 MB)
     Installing build dependencies ... error
     error: subprocess-exited-with-error

     × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
     │ exit code: 1
     ╰─> [10 lines of output]
         Collecting setuptools
           Using cached setuptools-65.5.1-py3-none-any.whl (1.2 MB)
         Collecting wheel
           Using cached wheel-0.38.2-py3-none-any.whl (36 kB)
         Collecting cython!=0.27,!=0.27.2,<=0.29.28,>=0.24
           Using cached Cython-0.29.28-py2.py3-none-any.whl (983 kB)
         Collecting kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev~=0.3.3
           Using cached kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev-0.3.3-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (3.9 MB)
         ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement kivy_deps.sdl2_dev~=0.4.5 (from    versions: 0.5.1)
         ERROR: No matching distribution found for kivy_deps.sdl2_dev~=0.4.5
         [end of output]

     note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
   error: subprocess-exited-with-error

   × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
   │ exit code: 1
   ╰─> See above for output.

   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

```
````

Researching about it and trying to install other libraries I found that it can be a situacion with one of the wheels, for what i tried to install the wheel i was suspecting that was missing for kivy from

```
https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/
```

but when trying to install it from the console, being in the path where the idle is (i put the wheel in the same place), the next message appears after i use the command:

````
   
```
 pip install Kivy-2.1.0-pp38-pypy38_pp73-win_amd64.whl
    ERROR: Kivy-2.1.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

```
````

And at the end because of that, even if the rest of the stuff are installed already kivy as so doesnt get installed. I suspect that the error is related to the fact that the wheel I'm trying to install is cp311 but in

```
https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/
```

there's only until cp310, but I don't know where to download cp311 from, looking through stack overflow I found some people say that kivy doesn't support python 3.10, mine is 3.11.0

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69791617/need-help-to-install-kivy
```

but i guess now it does, the thing is the same, my python is still more updated than the version kivy supports, but since the question is from a year ago I'm not sure if to uninsall python 3.11.0 and install 3.10 as they suggest.

Any light on the matter? I'd really appreciate it a lot,

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: There is currently no wheel available for Kivy on Python 3.11.  You have to compile Kivy from source to use it with Python 3.11.  I had the same problem and compiling Kivy from source worked for me.

Answer (score 20):

This cmd fixed the issue for my case-

```
pip install kivy[base] kivy_examples --pre --extra-index-url https://kivy.org/downloads/simple/
```

You might want to refer to https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/6806#issuecomment-608176268 for explanations

Answer (score 1):

[I'm using the translator] I was having this same problem, I managed to solve by uninstalling the old version of my python (3.11) and downloading version 3.10. That solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was python version.
I downgraded python to Kivy recommended version (3.7 - 3.11) and then it installs everithing without problem.